# Einstein's last attempt of a unified field theory

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, resource-recommendations, history, unified-theories

Are there any good sources on Einstein's attempt to unify general relativity with electrodynamics, a unified field theory, before he died?

Comment: General relativity and (classical), electrodynamics play together just fine. You can search for "Electrodynamics in curved spacetime", for more details. I think what you're getting at is the issues between general relativity and quantum mechanics/quantum field theory. I don't have a reference for Einstein's personal attempts, but I thought this might help point you in the right direction.

Comment: @CoffeeCrow I search for his personal attempt. And hoped somebody has a good source

Comment: Have you checked [Wikipedia's list of scientific publications by Albert Einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_scientific_publications_by_Albert_Einstein) ?

Comment: Try these https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2004-2 and https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2014-5

Comment: It is called **Teleparallel Gravity** (the name is because the curvature is zero but torsion is not. This implies the that the vectors do not change their orientation when transported parallel).

Comment: Try O'Raifeartaigh "The Dawning of Gauge Theory" and P. G. Bergman's text on General Relativity.  The appendix has detailed derivations of this type of theory.  These don't discuss Einstein's work specifically but do reference the approach of using additional dimensions are the metric to build up EM.  It does NOT work well, there are serious problems.  Einstein's own text 5th ed, discusses the Torsion field briefly but does not go into unified fields using it.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/384884/2451